# Do principal open sets in projective $n$ space define an open immersion of schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space, affine-geometry

I am currently in the midst of an algebraic geometry course. Recently we learned the definition of a projective morphism of schemes and that all projective morphisms are proper. However after carefully thinking through some examples I arrived at the following problem which has been baffling me for some hours.

It seems to me that we can define an open immersion of affine $n$-space into Proj $k(x_0, x_1, \cdots x_n)$ by taking the image of said immersion to be the principal open set $D_+(x_i)$ which is of course part of its affine cover. Clearly this is wrong though as that then implies the structure morphism from affine space to $k$ to be projective, thence proper and thus that the structure map is finite which is clearly ridiculous.

This is such a natural question that the fact it does not seem to have been asked before seems worrying to me and I suspect that there may be a problem with my mental definition of open immersion that I cannot find. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "that then implies..." How?

Comment: Well the morphism $k(x_0/x_i  \cdots  x_n/x_i ) = D_+
(x_i) \to k$ factors through $P^n_k$ right?

Comment: Yes, it factors through the morphism $\mathbf P^n_k \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} k$. But the open immersion is not proper.

Comment: Oh I missed a condition in my notes about needing the embedding to be a **closed** immersion. Thank you very much